# Cross-linguistic cases of German 'trennbare' Verbs

Tags: cross-linguistic

How many languages have verbs where you can detach a prefix and put it at the end? That's like the German 'trennbare' Verbs.

For example, in German, for depart/leave ('abfahren') you say:

`Der Zug is abgefahren.`
`The train has left.`

But:

`Der Zug fährt um 5 Uhr ab.`
`The train leaves at 5.`

Comment: Are you looking for a complete list?? A list of which of the roughly 7,000 existing languages have separable verbs?

Comment: It doesn't always go at the end; the important thing is that it's separable (_trennbar_) from its verb in some situations. The verb and its particle in English phrasal verbs like _look up (a book), walk through (the presentation),_ etc. are also separable, and they **must** be separated when there is a pronoun object. Viz, _He looked it up; He looked the book up, He looked up the book,_ but not *_He looked up it_.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe: maybe you are unable to find literature about this issue, but yes, there are scientific publication about these (and other) features.

Comment: @QuoraFeans I am not debating that there is literature about this topic. However, this question requests a list of all languages that have separable verbs.